# Is there metadata on files for OS on an external drive (USB)?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, metadata

If you store an operating system on an external drive, is there any metadata on the download origin/copy origin of the files? And if there is, can it be edited?
For example, if you download some linux variant on a USB and then copy the USB to another, is there any stored information about the original download, and can it be changed/deleted?

Alternatively, if you do the original download from a VM, will the metadata  show origin from the VM machine OS, the VM itself, or the default OS from the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

In a strict sense, no. There is no record about where the data comes from.

Yet: all data can be fingerprinted (see [Hash Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)):
So if you don't change the data at all, one could prove with dead precision that the data was copied from an original.

Some VM configurations contain this kind of data in form of volume hashes, and [UUID'S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as is the case for [VMware](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-533B2C4F-7BD5-41EB-8392-2B9FE687AE50.html).